# How to install Angular libraries with Angular 2 starter project?

Tags: angular, webpack

Is there a tutorial somewhere that shows how to install libraries like ng-boostrap with the Angular 2 starter project (webpack)?
Do we npm install then copy paste the folders?

Comment: `npm install --save`, but no copy and paste. Simply `import` them by name.

Comment: How to install a library depends only on the library itself.

Comment: Indeed Webpack magically handles everything. Awesome!